# Python MAPI Outlook read emails for a particular year

Tags: python, outlook, mapi

This func is for Year alone. (Doesn't work)

```
def daterange(args):
        
        user_inp = datetime.strptime(args,'%Y')

        rmail = object.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] == '" + user_inp.strftime('%Y')+"'")
        return rmail
```

The Restrict code doesn't work with = , throws error with == and only works with >=

My requirement is all mails from user_inp(2020) or 2019 etc

Please Help !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Restrict code doesn't work with = , throws error with == and only works with >=

Using the `equal` operator is not really a good idea. Instead, you need to specify the time and date range. The difference can be a minute, but not equal.

Read more about the date and time comparisons in Outlook on the [Filtering Items Using a Date-time Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/How-to/Search-and-Filter/filtering-items-using-a-date-time-comparison) page.

Comment: Hi @Eugene, thanks for the answer but lets say, the user wants all mails from only `2018`, is there no way to do this directly.

Comment: I could use Python and do something like user_input = 2018 + 1 to get 2019, then make a range but is there nothing like this in the API ???